# Merge Rest API results, merge/combine PowerShell objects

Tags: powershell

I am in the middle of exporting data from OMS Service Map using the Rest API in PowerShell. However the Rest API has a limitation of only a one hour time window in which to export the data.

I know I can loop across a larger time span in hourly blocks (like a ForEach), but how to I merge each result, so I don’t get duplicates, and only the changes or additions get added to the existing data.

```
 # Call to get everything in a service map
$mapRequest = @{'startTime' = $ScriptStartTime
                'endTime'= $ScriptEndTime
                'kind' = 'map:single-machine-dependency'
                'machineId' = $machineId} | ConvertTo-Json

### Post Header Creation
$enc = New-Object "System.Text.ASCIIEncoding"
$byteArray = $enc.GetBytes($mapRequest)
$contentLength = $byteArray.Length
$PostHeader = PostHeader $contentLength

### OMS Service Map API - per machine
$apicall = "$myAPIPath/features/serviceMap/generateMap?api-version=2015-11-01-preview"
$Uri = "{0}{1}" -f $APIURL, $apicall

$serverdep = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Headers $PostHeader -Body $mapRequest -Uri $uri
```

Here is the full script below which grabs data by using the default one hour window....

```
##########################################################################################
##################################     Credentials     ###################################
##########################################################################################


#region Logon to Azure & choose Azure subscription

### Log into Azure with an organisational account

$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString 'MyPasssword' -AsPlainText -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("0db3d52f-0976-40f7-bee3-745da7f2fe7d", $secpasswd)
$TenantId = 'Tennant-ID'
Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $TenantId

$Subscription = (Get-AzureRmSubscription | Out-GridView -Title "Choose a Source & Target Subscription ..." -PassThru)
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $Subscription.Id

#endregion

$ResourceGroupName = "azureroadmaprg"
$WorkSpaceName = "AzureRoadMap"
$SubscriptionId = $Subscription.Id

##########################################################################################
###################################    Functions     #####################################
##########################################################################################

Function RestAPI-UPN-AuthToken {

    $Username = $Cred.Username
    $Password = $Cred.Password
    $TenantId = $Subscription.TenantId

    # Load ADAL Azure AD Authentication Library Assemblies
    $adal = "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement\Azure\Services\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll"
    $adalforms = "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement\Azure\Services\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.WindowsForms.dll"
    $null = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($adal)
    $null = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($adalforms)

    $adTenant = $Subscription.TenantId
    # Client ID for Azure PowerShell
    $clientId = "1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2"
    # Set redirect URI for Azure PowerShell
    $redirectUri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"
    # Set Resource URI to Azure Service Management API | @marckean
    $resourceAppIdURIARM = "https://management.azure.com/"

    # Authenticate and Acquire Token

    # Set Authority to Azure AD Tenant
    $authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/$TenantId"
    # Build up the credentials
    $ClientCred = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential]::new($UserName, $Password)
    # Create Authentication Context tied to Azure AD Tenant
    $authContext = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext" -ArgumentList $authority
    # Acquire token
    $global:Token = $authContext.AcquireTokenAsync($resourceAppIdURIARM,$clientId,$ClientCred)
    }

Function RestAPI-SPN-AuthToken {

    $Username = $Cred.Username
    $Password = $Cred.Password
    $TenantId = $Subscription.TenantId

    # Set Resource URI to Azure Service Management API
    $resourceAppIdURI = 'https://management.core.windows.net/'

    # Set Authority to Azure AD Tenant
    $authority = "https://login.windows.net/$TenantId"

    # Build up the credentials
    $ClientCred = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential]::new($UserName, $Password)
    # Acquire token
    $authContext = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext]::new($authority)
    $global:Token = $authContext.AcquireTokenAsync($resourceAppIdURI,$ClientCred)
}

Function RequestHeader {

  # Create Authorization Header
  $authHeader = $global:Token.Result.CreateAuthorizationHeader()
  # Set HTTP request headers to include Authorization header | @marckean
  $requestHeader = @{
    "x-ms-version" = "2014-10-01"; #'2014-10-01'
    "Authorization" = $authHeader
  }
  return $RequestHeader
}

Function PostHeader ($contentLength) {

  # Create Authorization Header
  $authHeader = $global:Token.Result.CreateAuthorizationHeader()
  # Set HTTP request headers to include Authorization header | @marckean
  $PostHeader = @{
    "x-ms-version" = "2014-10-01"; #'2014-10-01'
    "x-ms-date" = ([DateTime]::UtcNow | Get-Date)
    "Authorization" = $authHeader
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
    "Content-Length"= $contentLength
  }
  return $PostHeader
}

##########################################################################################
#####################################     Token     ######################################
##########################################################################################

RestAPI-SPN-AuthToken # To Logon to Rest and get an an auth key

##########################################################################################
################################    Rest API metadata    #################################
##########################################################################################

$APIURL = 'https://management.azure.com'
$myAPIPath = "/subscriptions/$SubscriptionId/resourcegroups/$ResourceGroupName/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/$WorkSpaceName"

##########################################################################################
#########################     OMS Service Map Rest API calls     #########################
##########################################################################################

[string]$server = '*'
$endTime = ([DateTime]::UtcNow | Get-Date -Format s)
$startTime = ([DateTime]::UtcNow.AddHours(-1) | Get-Date -Format s)

$startTime = '2017-07-19T21:08:17'
$endTime = '2017-07-19T22:08:17'

# Get all machines in OMS $machines
$apicall = "$myAPIPath/features/serviceMap/machines?api-version=2015-11-01-preview&st=$startTime&et=$endTime"
$Uri = "{0}{1}" -f $APIURL, $apicall
$RequestHeader = RequestHeader
$AllMachines = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers $RequestHeader -Uri $uri

$csvContents = @() # Create the empty array that will eventually be the CSV file
#[ref]$csvContents

# Get all Machine Groups via API
$apicall = "$myAPIPath/features/serviceMap/machineGroups?api-version=2015-11-01-preview"
$Uri = "{0}{1}" -f $APIURL, $apicall
$RequestHeader = RequestHeader
$MachineGroups = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers $RequestHeader -Uri $uri

$ObjectResult = @()
# For each Machine
foreach($machine in ($Allmachines.value)
{
  if ($machine.properties.displayName -like $server)
  {
    $machineFound = $true
    $machineId = $machine.id

    # Call to get everything in a service map
    $mapRequest = @{'startTime' = $startTime
                    'endTime'= $endTime
                    'kind' = 'map:single-machine-dependency'
                    'machineId' = $machineId} | ConvertTo-Json

    ### Post Header Creation
    $enc = New-Object "System.Text.ASCIIEncoding"
    $byteArray = $enc.GetBytes($mapRequest)
    $contentLength = $byteArray.Length
    $PostHeader = PostHeader $contentLength

    ### OMS Service Map API - per machine
    $apicall = "$myAPIPath/features/serviceMap/generateMap?api-version=2015-11-01-preview"
    $Uri = "{0}{1}" -f $APIURL, $apicall

    $serverdep = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Headers $PostHeader -Body $mapRequest -Uri $uri
    $SMconnections = $serverdep.map.edges.connections
    $SMacceptors = $serverdep.map.edges.acceptors
    $SMClientGroups = $serverdep.map.nodes.clientGroups
    $SMprocesses = $serverdep.map.nodes.processes
    $SMmachines = $serverdep.map.nodes.machines
    $SMports = $serverdep.map.nodes.ports
    # Prosesses on remote machines
    $ExternalProcesses = $SMProcesses | ? {$_.properties.machine.id -ne $Machine.id}

##########################################################################################
#########################     Client Groups Per Hour and Per Machine
##########################################################################################

    ### OMS Client Groups - per machine
    $ClientGroupObject = @()
    foreach($SMClientGroup in $SMClientGroups)
    {

     # Client Group API
      $apicall = "$myAPIPath/features/serviceMap/clientGroups/$($SMClientGroup.name)/members?api-version=2015-11-01-preview&st=$startTime&et=$endTime"
      $Uri = "{0}{1}" -f $APIURL, $apicall
      $RequestHeader = RequestHeader
      $ClientGroupMembersAPI = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers $RequestHeader -Uri $Uri
      Start-Sleep -Seconds 1

      $CGMembers = @()
      0..(($ClientGroupMembersAPI.value).count -1) |
      % {$CGMembers += '{0} ({1})' -f ($ClientGroupMembersAPI.value)[$_].properties.ipAddress, ($ClientGroupMembersAPI.value)[$_].properties.port.properties.portNumber}

    # Custom Object
      $cgm = [PSCustomObject]@{

      #Connection = $connection.name
      ID = $SMClientGroup.id
      Name = $SMClientGroup.name
      Members = ($CGMembers -join ', ')
      MachineID = $machine.id
      ProcessName = ($SMprocesses | ? {$_.id -eq $SMClientGroup.properties.clientsOf.id}).properties.DisplayName
      ProcessID = ($SMprocesses | ? {$_.id -eq $SMClientGroup.properties.clientsOf.id}).id
    }

    $ClientGroupObject += $cgm

    }

##########################################################################################
#########################     ForEach Process - Per Machine Per Hour
##########################################################################################

    #nodes - The nodes (entities) of a map
    #Ports - Port resources
    #machines
    #processes
    #clientGroups
    #edges - The edges (relationships) of a map
    #connections - Network Connections
    #acceptors - Processes accepting on a port

    # Processes (Monitored) (not discovered, e.g. a discovered process is Port 443 (https))

    # Find inbound connections processes ID
      $InboundConnectionProcessIDs = ($SMconnections | ? {$_.properties.source.properties.machine -and $_.properties.destination.properties.machine.id -eq $machine.id}).properties.source.id
    foreach ($process in ($SMprocesses | ? {$_.properties.monitoringState -eq 'monitored' -and $ExternalProcesses.id -notcontains $_.id})) 
    {
      # -and $InboundConnectionProcessIDs -notcontains $_.id
      # -and $_.id -eq '/subscriptions/e390d230-7e20-466b-8350-5666b87f9dfb/resourceGroups/azureroadmaprg/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/AzureRoadMap/features/serviceMap/machines/m-0c14c199-5439-4b62-80ea-1f06dca736ae/processes/p-1f9551d7b5bab1947ac798affec7b0d52763d924'


      ##########################################################################################
      #########################     Network Details Clean-Up
      ##########################################################################################

          $ipv4s = @()
          foreach($interface in $machine.properties.networking.ipv4interfaces) {
            $ipv4s += $interface.ipAddress
          }

          $ipv6s = @()
          foreach($interface in $machine.properties.networking.ipv6interfaces) {
            $ipv6s += $interface.ipAddress
          }

      ##########################################################################################
      #########################     Outbound Connections - based on process
      ##########################################################################################
    # Outbound Connections - based on process
    $OutboundConnectionAgg = @(); $ConnectionMachineName = $null; $ConnectionPort = $null;$OutboundConnection = $null
    $obc1Result = @()
    foreach ($conn in ($SMconnections | ? {$_.properties.source.id -eq $process.id})){
    # Check to see if the destination doesn't contain the current machine's process and that destination machine is not the current machine

    $monitoringState = ($SMprocesses | ? {$_.id -eq $conn.properties.destination.id}).properties.monitoringState
    $monitoringState
    # Discovered Connections
    if($monitoringState -eq 'discovered' -and $conn.properties.destination.id -ne $process.id){

        $ConnectionPort = $conn.properties.serverPort.properties.portNumber
        $MachineID = $conn.properties.destination.properties.machine.id
        $ConnectionMachineName = ($SMmachines | ? {$_.id -eq $MachineID}).properties.displayName
        $DestinationPortID = ($SMports | ? {$_.id -eq $conn.properties.serverPort.id}).id
        $ipAddress = ($SMports | ? {$_.id -eq $DestinationPortID}).properties.ipAddress
        $FailureState = $conn.properties.failureState

        # Custom Object
        $obc1 = new-object psObject | select TargetMachineName,ServerPort,DestinationProcessName,FailureState

        $obc1.TargetMachineName = $ConnectionMachineName
        $obc1.ServerPort = $ConnectionPort
        $obc1.DestinationProcessName = $ipAddress
        $obc1.FailureState = $FailureState

        $obc1Result += $obc1
            }
        }


    # External Process
    $obc2Result = @() 
    if($monitoringState -eq 'monitored' -and $conn.properties.destination.id -ne $process.id){

    $SourceProcessname = ($SMprocesses | ? {$_.id -eq $conn.properties.source.id}).properties.displayName
    $SourceProcessID = ($SMprocesses | ? {$_.id -eq $conn.properties.source.id}).id
    $SourceProcessVersionName = ($SMprocesses | ? {$_.id -eq $conn.properties.source.id}).properties.details.productVersion
    $DestinationProcessName = ($SMprocesses | ? {$_.id -eq $conn.properties.destination.id}).properties.displayName
    $DestinationProcessID = ($SMprocesses | ? {$_.id -eq $conn.properties.destination.id}).id
    $DestinationProcessVersionName = ($SMprocesses | ? {$_.id -eq $conn.properties.destination.id}).properties.details.productVersion
    $TargetMachineID = ($SMmachines | ? {$_.id -eq $conn.properties.destination.properties.machine.id}).id
    $TargetMachineName = ($SMmachines | ? {$_.id -eq $TargetMachineID}).properties.displayName
    $ServerPortID = $SMports | ? {$_.id -eq $conn.properties.serverPort.id}
    $ServerPort = $ServerPortID.properties.portNumber
    $FailureState = $conn.properties.failureState

        # Custom Object
        $obc2 = new-object psObject | select TargetMachineName,ServerPort,DestinationProcessName,FailureState

        $obc2.TargetMachineName = $TargetMachineName
        $obc2.ServerPort = $ServerPort
        $obc2.DestinationProcessName = $DestinationProcessName
        $obc2.FailureState = $FailureState

        $obc2Result += $obc2
       }    

      ##########################################################################################
      #########################     Inbound Connections - based on process
      ##########################################################################################
      # Outbound Connections - based on process
      $ibc1Result = @();$ibc2Result = @()
      $InboundConnection = $null; $InboundConnectionAgg = @(); $ConnectionMachineName = $null; $ConnectionPort = $null
      if(($SMconnections) | ? {$_.properties.destination.id -eq $process.id})
      {

        # Client Groups
          # Match the connection destination to a source client group
        if($ClientGroupObject.Processid -contains $process.id)
          {

            # Client Group Members            
            foreach ($obj in ($ClientGroupObject | ? {$_.Processid -eq $process.id -and $_.ProcessName})){

            $members = $obj.Members
            $ConnectionMachineName = "ClientGroup{0}" -f (Get-Random -Minimum 1111 -Maximum 9999999)

            # Custom Object
            $ibc1 = new-object psObject | select ConnectionMachineName,ProcessName

            $ibc1.ConnectionMachineName = $ConnectionMachineName
            $ibc1.ProcessName = $members

            $ibc1Result += $ibc1

            }
          }

        foreach ($conn in ($SMconnections | ? {$_.properties.destination.id -eq $process.id -and $_.properties.source.type -notmatch 'workspaces/features/clientGroups'})) {

              $ProcessID = $conn.properties.destination.id
              $ProcessName = ($SMprocesses | ? {$_.id -eq $conn.properties.source.id}).properties.displayName
              $MachineID = ($SMmachines | ? {$_.id -eq $conn.properties.source.properties.machine.id}).id
              $ConnectionMachineName = ($SMmachines | ? {$_.id -eq $conn.properties.source.properties.machine.id}).properties.displayName

            # Custom Object
            $ibc2 = new-object psObject | select ConnectionMachineName,ProcessName

            $ibc2.ConnectionMachineName = $ConnectionMachineName
            $ibc2.ProcessName = $ProcessName

            $ibc2Result += $ibc2
                }
          }

      ##########################################################################################
      #########################     Machine Group Membership
      ##########################################################################################                    
          # Get Machine Group Membership
          $MachineGroupMembership = @()
          foreach($MachineGroup in $MachineGroups.value){
            if($MachineGroup.properties.machines.properties.displayNameHint -contains $machine.properties.displayName){
              $MachineGroupMembership += $MachineGroup.properties.displayName
            }
          }

      ##########################################################################################
      #########################     Custom Object
      ##########################################################################################  

$inboundConnections = (($ibc1Result + $ibc2Result) | % {('({0}, {1})' -f $_.ConnectionMachineName, $_.ProcessName)}) -join ', '
$outboundConnections = (($obc1Result + $obc2Result) | % {('({0}, {1}, {2}, {3})' -f $_.TargetMachineName, $_.ServerPort, $_.DestinationProcessName, $_.FailureState)}) -join ', '

        # Custom Object
        $s = [PSCustomObject]@{

            #Connection = $connection.name
            ServerName = $machine.properties.displayName
            MachineGroupMembership = $MachineGroupMembership -join ' '
            Ipv4s = ([system.String]::Join(", ", $ipv4s))
            Ipv6s = ([system.String]::Join(", ", $ipv6s))
            OsFamily = $machine.properties.operatingsystem.family
            OsName = $machine.properties.operatingsystem.fullName
            Memory = $machine.properties.resources.physicalmemory
            Cpus = $machine.properties.resources.cpus
            CpuSpeed = $machine.properties.resources.cpuSpeed
            VmType = $machine.properties.virtualMachine.virtualMachineType
            #ClientMachine = (. ( {"client"},{$clientMachine.properties.displayName})[$clientMachine.properties.displayName -ne $null])
            #InboundConnections = (@(($InboundConnection) -join ',') | Out-String).Trim()
            InboundConnections = $inboundConnections
            Process = (. ( {"n/a"},{$Process.properties.displayName})[$Process.properties.displayName -ne $null])
            OutboundConnection = $outboundConnections

        }
        $ObjectResult += $s

        }
    }
}




$csvName = "Migration_" + [DateTime]::Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss") + ".html"
#$csvName = "output.csv"

$ObjectResult | Sort-Object Process | ConvertTo-Html | Set-Content -Path $csvName

# Write CSV
$ObjectResult | Select-Object @{name="multistring";Expression={$_.InboundConnections -join ';'}} | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation -Path $csvName
```

Comment: Create an additional hashtable. Enumerate each incoming object and check if its key is already in the table, skip adding or add the object and store the key in the table accordingly. Without an example of actual data I doubt it's possible to provide a certain answer though.

Comment: I edited the original question and pasted my entire script, which works for the one hour limitation. I need to loop this at the top, where it does the API call for the Service Map      `$myAPIPath/features/serviceMap/generateMap?api-version=2015-11-01-preview`  I need to loop this part with dates (which I have the script to do this) however I need to work out how to merge the `$serverdep` variable, each loop, each one hour time window, building this up to represent a much larger time span.

Comment: Is there some unique id property in the server results? Otherwise you'd need to compare all properties.

Comment: there's an (ID) field in each of the 5 variable subfolders.

Comment: FWIW here's an example of what I suggested http://p.ip.fi/bqNV

Comment: Ok, let me try this and see how it goes